# Naming Convention. Add a value in a form that is never used just to change the scale

Tags: statistics

Let's say i have a form like this

How fast can you run?

6km/h
12km/h
24km/h
48km/h

Now, we all know that the human being can't run at 48km/h.From a statistic point of view, adding this value will impact the overall perception of the answers. i.e.: the median of the available values is different.

I think this is a psychological practice.
I wonder if this technique has a specific name

Comment: That's a great question. I'm sure you're aware that it's done with prices too: put a crappy cheapo item at the bottom of the price range and a way too expensive one at the top to encourage people to buy the other things on the list. You might get more traction for this question on on stats.stackexchange.com.